# too many decimals + styling not visible on website

Tags: javascript, colors, styling, decimal

My script below displays too many decimal points in the return value

also, when i posted the code onto my website, it did not display all the text styling that i added

can you please tell me what im missing?

thanks

```
<html>

    <head>
    <style>
            body {color:rgb(128,128,128);}
            p.3 {color:rgb(128,128,128);}
            p.3 {font-size:20PX;}
    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function convert() {
        var Amount=document.getElementById('amount');
        var Currency=document.getElementById('currency');
        var Converted=document.getElementById('converted');
        var Choice=document.getElementById('choice');
        var AED=1;
        var US=0.27;
        var QR=0.99;
        var SR=1.02;
        var KD=0.0778;
        var BD=0.102;

        switch(document.converter.currency.value) {
            case "US Dollars" :
                document.converter.converted.value=US*document.converter.amount.value;
                document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
            break;
            case "Qatar Riyal":
                document.converter.converted.value=QR*document.converter.amount.value;
                document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
            break;
            case "Saudi Riyal":
                document.converter.converted.value=SR*document.converter.amount.value;
                document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
            break;
            case "Kuwaiti Dinar":
                document.converter.converted.value=KD*document.converter.amount.value;
                document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
            break;
            case "Bahrain Dinar":
                document.converter.converted.value=BD*document.converter.amount.value;
                document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
            break;
        }
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divWrapper">
        <form name="converter" id="converter">
        <br/> Enter amount in UAE Dirhams
        <input name="amount"type="text" id="amount" size="3" />
        <br /><br /> 
        Please Select a currency <select name="currency" id="currency">
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option value="US Dollars">US Dollars</option>
        <option value="Qatar Riyal">Qatar Riyal</option>
        <option value="Saudi Riyal">Saudi Riyal</option>
        <option value="Kuwaiti Dinar">Kuwaiti Dinar</option>
        <option value="Bahrain Dinar">Bahrain Dinar</option>
        </select> 

        <input type="button" name="convt" id="convt" onclick="convert()" value="Convert" />
        <br /><br /> 
        <p class="3"> The amount is:
        <input name="converted" type="text" id="converted" style="border:0px" style="color:rgb(255,0,102)" style="text-align:center" style="font-size:22PX"  value="" size="5"/>
        in 
        <input name="choice" type="text" id="choice" style="border:0px" style="color:rgb(255,0,102)" style="font-size:22PX" style="text-align:center" value="" size="10"> </p>

        <br /><br />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give some example values for what you're supplying when you test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regarding the Javascript/Decimals

Assuming that you want things rounded to two decimal places, you should employ the `.toFixed()` function, as [tschulze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216149/259014) mentioned.

Here's how to incorporate that into your current structure (you'll have to do similar things to each of your case statements):

```
document.converter.converted.value=(BD*document.converter.amount.value).toFixed(2);
document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
```

---

#### Regarding the Styling

The issues that you are having with styling are due to having multiple style attributes. The correct way to apply multiple styles is to have all of the different aspects that you are setting inside one style attribute, separated by semicolons:

```
<input name="converted" type="text" id="converted" style="border:0; color:rgb(255,0,102); text-align:center; font-size:22PX;" value="" size="5"/>
```

---

#### Additional Notes

It seems like you could really simplify your code by switching to a structure where you have a single set multiplier and just choose which to apply by the case it is fitting:

```
function convert() {
    var Amount=document.getElementById('amount');
    var Currency=document.getElementById('currency');
    var Converted=document.getElementById('converted');
    var Choice=document.getElementById('choice');
    var multiplier=1;

    switch(document.converter.currency.value) {
        case "US Dollars" : multiplier=0.27; break;
        case "Qatar Riyal": multiplier=0.99; break;
        case "Saudi Riyal": multiplier=1.02; break;
        case "Kuwaiti Dinar": multiplier=0.0778; break;
        case "Bahrain Dinar": multiplier=0.102; break;
    }
    
     document.converter.converted.value=(multiplier*document.converter.amount.value).toFixed(2);
     document.converter.choice.value=document.converter.currency.value;
}
```

Comment: Appreciated the time you took to elaborate on the answers, this is amazing support. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote answers when that is the case (those actions are much of what makes StackOverflow work)

Comment: Excellent thanks for letting me know about the answer part. Im relatively new and just getting around. Am out right now and will try it as soon as I reach home and close it accordingly. Than you so much again for the help and the time u took to answer my q

Comment: Hi again, i tried the above and the styling works perfect, thanks !!! :D however the function .toFixed(2) stops the whole thing from working...any idea why it might be doing so? thanks a ton, literally !!

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function requires the variable/value that you are calling it on to be of numeric type. If you got the parenthesis off in the code I had above, then it might try to apply that to a string instead. You can also try separating the `.toString()` from the calculation (do the calculation first, then call `.toString()` separately on the result.

Comment: Thanks again Jeffrey, but i will need to sit for some time and break down what you said into how to apply it to my code LOL just because i'm new to javascript. Will probably do this tomorrow morning as it's 11Pm here...Nevertheless, you've been great help and i thank you very much for your support today :) God bless !!

Comment: That last comment of mine was rushed...A coworker was asking me questions at the same time and I made a few typos: everywhere that I said `.toString()`, I meant `.toFixed()`. Keep that in mind when you're looking over this!

Answer (score 1):

just for the JavaScript:

if you want to format a number to a fixed numbers of decimals, call

```
.toFixed()
```

on it.

for example:

```
var i = 3.4444

var num = i.toFixed(2) //num = 3.44, but as a string
```

look here for more: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5)